# Upgrade killed my access to Brother scanner. No gscan2pdf, xsane etc. (Brother MFC-8480DN) Here is how I fixed it

Tags: drivers, scanner

First, I went to the Brother site and downloaded the driver and key.  [welcome.solutions.brother.com](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html)

I installed the driver and key by clicking on them and installing via the Ubuntu Software Center.  The Center informed me that the files were of poor quality.  I informed the Center to proceed as directed and not give me any backtalk.

Second, I added the scanner to libsane.rules using the terminal to get root access to the editor:

```
sudo gedit '/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules'
```

Then I inserted language before the following line in that file:

```
"# The following rule will disable USB autosuspend for the device"
```

Here is the language to add:

```
# Brother scanners

ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

Third, I saved the file, closed the editor, closed the terminal, rebooted.

How to fix this ?

Comment: Rater than giving an answer as a question this site works better if we separate questions from answers. You are most welcome to write an answer to your own question to share your valuable experience.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing drivers for Brother AIO printer drivers which has scanner function, which found in Main Ubuntu Repository

```
sudo apt-get install brother-lpr-drivers-ac brother-lpr-drivers-bh7 brother-lpr-drivers-common brother-lpr-drivers-extra brother-lpr-drivers-laser brother-lpr-drivers-laser1 brother-cups-wrapper-extra
```